# Sorting an array of objects reference of other array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays of objects

```
   const reference_array= [{"key":"oAuthAccessToken","label":"Access Token","value":""},{"key":"clientId","label":"Client ID","value":""},{"label":"Verification Token","key":"verificationToken","value":""},{"label":"User ID","key":"userId","value":""},{"key":"signingSecret","label":"Signing Secret","value":""},{"label":"App ID","key":"appId","value":""},{"label":"Team ID","key":"teamId","value":""},{"label":"Name","key":"name","value":""},{"label":"Client Secret","key":"clientSecret","value":""},{"label":"ID","key":"id","value":""},{"label":"Channel ID","key":"channelId","value":""},{"key":"","value":""}]

   const resArray = [{"key":"3111","value":"12111"},{"key":"656556","value":"55666664"},{"key":"oAuthAccessToken","value":"123"},{"key":"clientId","value":"5"},{"key":"webhook_URL","value":"https://api.slack.com/1.1/account_activity/all/dev/webhooks.json?ref=7364616106833455"},{"key":"verificationToken","value":"55525"},{"key":"userId","value":"254"},{"key":"createdDate","value":"2019-09-05T07:47:24Z"},{"key":"createdBy","value":"John"},{"key":"webhook_ID","value":"7364616106833455"},{"key":"signingSecret","value":"12476233"},{"key":"appId","value":"9886"},{"key":"teamId","value":"8955653563"},{"key":"name","value":"56565"},{"key":"clientSecret","value":"656665656"},{"key":"id","value":"5656565"},{"key":"channelId","value":"55655565"}]
```

I would like to sort the resArray based on order of reference_array, the similar things of the two arrays is key value.

How to sort the resArray based on order of reference_array.

I tried in many ways but i have no luck.please help me to resolve the issue like below

Thanks in advance

```
resArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return reference_array.map(function(x) {return x.key; }).indexOf(b) - reference_array.map(function(x) {return x.key; }).indexOf(a);
});
```

Expected Output :

```
const resArray = [{
        "key": "oAuthAccessToken",
        "value": "123"
    }, {
        "key": "clientId",
        "value": "5"
    }, {
        "key": "verificationToken",
        "value": "55525"
    }, {
        "key": "userId",
        "value": "254"
    }, {
        "key": "signingSecret",
        "value": "12476233"
    }, {
        "key": "appId",
        "value": "9886"
    }, {
        "key": "teamId",
        "value": "8955653563"
    }, {
        "key": "name",
        "value": "56565"
    }, {
        "key": "clientSecret",
        "value": "656665656"
    }, {
        "key": "id",
        "value": "5656565"
    }, {
        "key": "channelId",
        "value": "55655565"
    }, {
        "key": "3111",
        "value": "12111"
    }, {
        "key": "656556",
        "value": "55666664"
    }, {
        "key": "webhook_URL",
        "value": "https://api.slack.com/1.1/account_activity/all/dev/webhooks.json?ref=7364616106833455"
    }, {
        "key": "createdDate",
        "value": "2019-09-05T07:47:24Z"
    }, {
        "key": "createdBy",
        "value": "John"
    },
    {
        "key": "webhook_ID",
        "value": "7364616106833455"
    }
]
```

Comment: Sorting on which keys, Please put the expected outcome

Comment: Reference array keys

Comment: i updated expected output in question @NeelRathod

Comment: How is the reference_array sorted? If it is sorted on "key" then you should be able to sort resArray the same way. What if they get out of sync and one has "key" items that the other doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object as reference for the sorting order and take `Infinity` for unknown key for sorting this items to the bottom of the array.

```js
var reference = [{ key: "oAuthAccessToken", label: "Access Token", value: "" }, { key: "clientId", label: "Client ID", value: "" }, { label: "Verification Token", key: "verificationToken", value: "" }, { label: "User ID", key: "userId", value: "" }, { key: "signingSecret", label: "Signing Secret", value: "" }, { label: "App ID", key: "appId", value: "" }, { label: "Team ID", key: "teamId", value: "" }, { label: "Name", key: "name", value: "" }, { label: "Client Secret", key: "clientSecret", value: "" }, { label: "ID", key: "id", value: "" }, { label: "Channel ID", key: "channelId", value: "" }, { key: "", value: "" }],
    array = [{ key: "3111", value: "12111" }, { key: "656556", value: "55666664" }, { key: "oAuthAccessToken", value: "123" }, { key: "clientId", value: "5" }, { key: "webhook_URL", value: "https://api.slack.com/1.1/account_activity/all/dev/webhooks.json?ref=7364616106833455" }, { key: "verificationToken", value: "55525" }, { key: "userId", value: "254" }, { key: "createdDate", value: "2019-09-05T07:47:24Z" }, { key: "createdBy", value: "John" }, { key: "webhook_ID", value: "7364616106833455" }, { key: "signingSecret", value: "12476233" }, { key: "appId", value: "9886" }, { key: "teamId", value: "8955653563" }, { key: "name", value: "56565" }, { key: "clientSecret", value: "656665656" }, { key: "id", value: "5656565" }, { key: "channelId", value: "55655565" }],
    order = reference.reduce((o, { key }, i) => (o[key] = i + 1, o), {});

array.sort((a, b) => (order[a.key] || Infinity) - (order[b.key] || Infinity));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```